# add JSX element through state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm making a chat log which will display userA and userB chat conversation.

**My initial state:**

```
var initialState = {
  message: '', //my input message
  receivedMessage: null //all old messages
}
```

**My handling function when click *send* button:**

```
handleSend = () => {
    var message = () => {
        return (<p className="my-text">{this.state.yourName + ": " + this.state.message}</p>);
    };
    var oldMessages = this.state.receivedMessage;
    this.setState({receivedMessage: oldMessages + message, message: ''});
    dataChannel.send(message); //WEBRTC data channel
}
```

**My handling received message function:**

```
receiveChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
                var oldMessages = this.state.receivedMessage;
                var userB = this.state.callToUser;
                var message = () => {
                    return (<p className="receive-text">{userB}: event.data</p>);
                }
                this.setState({
                    receivedMessage: oldMessages + message
                })
        };
```

**My JSX element which store the conversation:**

```
<div className="panel-body text-left">{this.state.receivedMessage}</div>
```

But this didn't work, I don't get the display I want. Can anybody tell me where did I do wrong and give me a solution for this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How exactly are things not working the way you want them to? See [mcve] for details about asking a question which can be answered.

Comment: But as a counterpoint, the state and params of a React component are usually simple JavaScript objects, rather than other components like in your case. You should make `receivedMessages` be just a list of strings or similar and then build the paragraphs from it in your `render` function.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try